# Ethernet Internet Access Issues on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, internet

I'm fairly new to Linux and I'm having an issue where while I'm using ethernet only certain websites load. Mostly Google owned ones, but also Netflix works. My problem is many websites do not load. Everything was okay during the first boot and I didn't notice until Discord and Spotify wouldn't load. When my computer is on WiFi everything works fine. I don't even know what to look for since everything in the network config tabs seems to the same between the WiFi and ethernet connections.

My motherboard is an x570 Strix-E and has a 2.5 Gbe and 1 Gbe ports on the motherboard. Currently I'm using the 2.5 Gbe port to a switch that connects to my router. I have tried using the 1 Gbe and it has the same effect. In addition I have a dual 10 Gbe card that's used to connect to a server. The 10 Gbe do not have access the internet and are set up on an IP 10.10.10.2 to interact with the server only. The system is dual booted with Windows and everything works in Windows the way I'd like for it to. Except I'd prefer Kubuntu to be my primary operating system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in Advance :)

Edit 1: The WiFi stopped working as well. My MTU is set to automatic and I'm using Verizon FiOS. I've tried setting my MTU to 1400 and 1500 but neither resolved my issue.

Edit 2: Sorry for lacking details. By doesn't load I mean that I receive the standard unable to establish a connection page from firefox. The errors reads:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at www.reddit.com.
     - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments
     - If you are unable to load any pages, check you computer's netwrok connection
     - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web
```

To the best of my knowledge I am not using a Proxy or Custom DNS server or a firewall beyond the defaults that would be used for an ASUS router and the initial set up for a Kubuntu installation. The connections for the 10Gbe is custom but all I did was set the IP and gateway to 10.10.10.2 and 255.0.0.0. The 2.5 Gbe was reset to defaults after fiddling with the MTU size.

Edit 3: I made a diagram of my internet set up using Pinta
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8STpm.png
Basically everything in my bedroom goes through a switch in a pretty typical way, but then also there's an ethernet cable that goes between a file server and my desktop if that helps explain a bit better? The red line represents a 10 Gbe connection, black represents 1 Gbe connections, and blue is WiFi. Thank you for all of the help and sorry that I'm not better at explaining the issue!

Comment: Are you using DSL? What is your MTU set to?

Comment: The router is 192.168.1.1. My server is 10.10.10.1, and the 10Gbe conneciton on my computer is 10.10.10.2. The 10 Gbe connection is working just fine, the 2.5 Gbe connection to my router is working, but I don't have access to certain sites.